# How to plot multiple charts using matplotlib from unstacked dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

This is a sample of the dataset I have using the following piece of code

```
ComplaintCity = nyc_df.groupby(['City','Complaint Type']).size().sort_values().unstack()
top5CitiesByComplaints = ComplaintCity[top5Complaints].rename_axis(None, axis=1)
top5CitiesByComplaints
```

```
    Blocked Driveway    Illegal Parking Noise - Street/Sidewalk Noise - Commercial  Derelict Vehicle
City                    
ARVERNE 35.0    58.0    29.0    2.0 27.0
ASTORIA 2734.0  1281.0  500.0   1554.0  363.0
BAYSIDE 377.0   514.0   15.0    40.0    198.0
BELLEROSE   95.0    106.0   13.0    37.0    89.0
BREEZY POINT    3.0 15.0    1.0 4.0 3.0
BRONX   12754.0 7859.0  8890.0  2433.0  1952.0
BROOKLYN    28147.0 27461.0 13354.0 11458.0 5179.0
CAMBRIA HEIGHTS 147.0   76.0    25.0    12.0    115.0
CENTRAL PARK    NaN 2.0 95.0    NaN NaN
COLLEGE POINT   435.0   352.0   33.0    35.0    184.0
CORONA  2761.0  660.0   238.0   248.0
```

I want to be able to plot the same as a horizontal bar chart for each complaint. It should display the Cities with the highest count of complaints. Something similar to the image below. I am not sure how to go about it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of axis instances with `subplots` and plot the columns one-by-one:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,2,figsize=(10,6))
for c,ax in zip(df.columns, axes.ravel()):
    df[c].sort_values().plot.barh(ax=ax)

fig.tight_layout()
```

Then you would get something like this:

[image]

Comment: probably should do a dropna() also before the sort_values?

Comment: It's up to OP to choose to plot `nan` values or not, but yes, that's a good suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: awesome that works. One final thing how can I add the title. say which chart belongs to which complaint

Comment: add `ax.set_title(c)` inside the for loop.